# Python List get first n elements by each unique value

Tags: python, list, unique

I have a list like ;

```
    [('10', '100'),
     ('11', '100'),
     ('18', '108'),
     ('22', '100'),
     ('12', '102'),
     ('15', '104'),
     ('21', '100'),
     ('25', '108'),
     ('20', '102'),
     ('24', '104'),
     ('105', '108'),
     ('35', '100'),
     ('14', '104'),
     ('96', '100'),
     ('100', '104'),
     ('26', '100'),
     ('19', '100'),
     ('110', '108'),
     ('36', '102'),
     ('30', '104')]
```

All items second values are uniquely '100','102,'104' and '108'.

I want to take first 3 values of '100','102','104','108' groups.

Output should look like this:

```
    [('10', '100'),
     ('11', '100'),
     ('22', '100'),
     ('18', '108'),
     ('25', '108'),
     ('105', '108'),
     ('12', '102'),
     ('20', '102'),
     ('36', '102'),
     ('15', '104'),
     ('24', '104'),
     ('14', '104')]
```

I dont want to change list to dataframe and make dataframe works.

Comment: You forgot to include the code you wrote when you attempted this.

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far to solve your homework assignment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
new_d = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in groupby(sorted(d, key=lambda x:int(x[-1])), key=lambda x:int(x[-1]))]
result = [b for _, c in new_d for b in c[:3]]
```

Output:

```
[('10', '100'), 
('11', '100'), 
('22', '100'), 
('12', '102'), 
('20', '102'), 
('36', '102'), 
('15', '104'), 
('24', '104'), 
('14', '104'), 
('18', '108'), 
('25', '108'), 
('105', '108')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the list of tuples, and keep track of how many times the second element in the tuples has appeared using a dictionary. Then simply add a tuple to the resulting list if its second value has appeared less than `3` times:

```
d = {}
n = 3
out = []
for i,j in l:
    if d.setdefault(j,0) < n:
        d[j]+= 1
        out.append((i,j))
```

---

```
print(out)

[('10', '100'),
 ('11', '100'),
 ('18', '108'),
 ('22', '100'),
 ('12', '102'),
 ('15', '104'),
 ('25', '108'),
 ('20', '102'),
 ('24', '104'),
 ('105', '108'),
 ('14', '104'),
 ('36', '102')]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to keep a simple count of the appearances of the keys in a dictionary, then sort it, for example (assuming an input data as in the question):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count
from operator import itemgetter

counts = defaultdict(lambda: count(0))
result = [(value, key) for value, key in data if next(counts[key]) < 3]

print(sorted(result, key=itemgetter(1)))
```

**Output**

```
[('10', '100'), ('11', '100'), ('22', '100'), ('12', '102'), ('20', '102'), ('36', '102'), ('15', '104'), ('24', '104'), ('14', '104'), ('18', '108'), ('25', '108'), ('105', '108')]
```

For more details see [count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).